# How to load an html page in perl

Tags: perl, cgi

Right now when i go to a link with the href of "myproject.local/cgi-bin/routes.cgi?page=reports" it just shows the header and redirect status in plain text.

how can i make it so that it actually loads the page that i've given it in the redirect url?

```
my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->header();
print $q->redirect('http://integrationsperl.local/reports.html');
```

Please help, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't make a separate call to [`header`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Creating-a-standard-http-header).

Calling [`redirect`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Generating-a-redirection-header) is generating a redirection header.

```
my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->redirect('http://integrationsperl.local/reports.html');
```

Outputs:

```
Status: 302 Found
Location: http://integrationsperl.local/reports.html
```

Comment: Is this the standard way to load pages in Perl? i.e. if a user clicks a link, this would be the way to load a new page for them after performing some logic server side?

Comment: Yes. You can also use named arguments `-nph` and `status`. [See the documentation for more details](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#GENERATING-A-REDIRECTION-HEADER).